# Is there a better way to utilize redshift, python, and powershell to automate my report?

Tags: python, powershell, automation, amazon-redshift

I'm automating my current reports and need help getting up and running.

I have a PS script that first fixes a csv file and then calls a python script. Within the python script I am importing modules that 'cannot be found' when the PS script runs.

I have tried importing the modules separately(but within the powershell script) to no avail. I have been trying to run from PyCharms using a powershell plugin. Even though I have tried running it in Powershell IDE and it produces the same error.

This is where it chokes. If I need to delve further please let me know and I will remove the sensitive information in the code and post it.

```
#POWERSHELL CODE
#start excel
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application

#make it visible (just to check what is happening)
$Excel.Visible = $true

#open file
$FilePath = 'file path here'
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets

#change column format type for DateTime issue in logs
$workbook.ActiveSheet.Columns.Item("X").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
$Output.ExitCode

#save doc and close excel
$ext=".csv"
$path="file here"
$workbook.SaveAs($path) 
$workbook.Close
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = 'False'
$Excel.Quit()
$Output.ExitCode


python "file here"  #calling python script here

$Output.ExitCode


#PYTHON CODE
import MySQLConnection2 as mc
import RedshiftConnection2 as rc
from Data_download2 import dict_to_csv
from os.path import join, basename
import datetime
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
```

The python code generates several csv files that are needed for this report. Once I get past this choke I will need to call another python script and then alter the csv files.

Error Message > 'Import-Module : The specified module 'SQLalchemy' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module 
directory.'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Import-Module` on python scripts and python modules.

Comment: I should have specified - I used `Import-Module` _after_ getting the same error several times. It can be taken out and will still produce the same error.

Comment: So the PowerShell Excel code produces the error? The error message in your initial question leads to the assumption, that ```Import-Module : The specified module 'SQLalchemy ' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.``` is the issue.

Comment: From a Powershell script, I am running a python script that imports modules inside of that (specifically sqlalchemy, numpy, and a personal file that contains credentials). SQL is needed in the python code but not in powershell.

Comment: According to your question, the two ```Import-Module``` statements, that import a python file (```MySQLConnection2.py```) and a python module (```SQLalchemy```), are in your PowerShell code.

Comment: Yes. But, those statements can be taken out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that if you stick the two ```Import-Module``` statements in the python code, that will also break.

Comment: Then I guess the ```Import-Module : The specified module 'SQLalchemy' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory``` goes away too. The interesting thing is, what the error message then is.

Comment: Yes, it is still `ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy`

Comment: And if you only run line 1 to 24?

Comment: And what happens when you run ```python "file here"```?